# Overloaded __lt__ operator unexpectedly called

Tags: python, qt, sorting, operator-overloading

I have QTableWidget with first column populated with checkable items, so I needed to overload those items to be able to sort them:

```
class CheckBoxItem(QtGui.QTableWidgetItem): 
    def __init__(self, doSelect):
        QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.__init__(self, doSelect)
        self.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        if doSelect:
            self.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        else:
            self.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

    def __lt__(self, other):        
        return self.checkState() < other.checkState()
```

It works as expected when I click on header of that column: rows are sorted - first there are checked rows and then not checked.

**Problem** occures when I don't click on header of any column and then use `tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(1)` , in that situation `__lt__` is called 100+ times if I have ~15 rows and mix some rows randomly, not sorting them. 
I've checked/unchecked some items before I call `setSortingEnabled(1)`, but I do not expect `__lt__` to compare them because I didn't clicked on header of that column to sort them.

I have 6 columns (0-5) and if I didn't clicked on header of any of them to sort, `tableWidget.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorSection()` returns `6` - which is column outside of table, which means that table is not sorted.

**So, why `__lt__` is called?** Did I miss something while overriding it?
I get idea that this would solve the problem (to compare items only if header of that column is clicked), but how to pass `sortIndicatorSection` to `__lt__`  ?

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    if sortIndicatorSection==0:
         return self.checkState() < other.checkState()
```

please help me, I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this. It turns out that `tableWidget.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorSection()` returns "6" (I don't know why) but sorting behaves like it is 0 ,as it is writen in docs:

```
    int QHeaderView::sortIndicatorSection () const
```

> Returns the logical index of the section that has a sort indicator. 
>    By default this is section 0.

This might be because I have tableWidget and not tableView.

So I've found this:

```
void QHeaderView::setSortIndicator ( int logicalIndex, Qt::SortOrder order )
```

> Sets the sort indicator for the section specified by the given
>   logicalIndex in the direction specified by order, and removes the sort
>   indicator from any other section that was showing it.
>
> logicalIndex may be -1, in which case no sort indicator will be shown
>   and the model will return to its natural, unsorted order. Note that
>   not all models support this and may even crash in this case.

It works for QTableWidget. I've put this line before table is populated `tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicator(-1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)`  ...that solved my problem.